# Ember - this.get(one from an array)

Tags: ember.js

So I've got two versions of this question, one a little simplified, one a bit more like what I'm trying to achieve.

1. I have a "student" model and a "score" model. The "student" has many "scores". On the "student" controller, I'm trying to set a computed property "score" equal to a specified one of these "scores".

Is there some way I can pass in another argument (eg, so as return the first in the array)?

In controllers/student

```
    score: function(){
                return this.get('scores', 1);
           }.property('scores')
```

2. An extra dimension here. The "score" model also belongs To an "objective" model. Can I set the "score" property on my "student" controller depending on the id of a chosen objective?

   -------------------------------------------**Update**----------------------------------------------------------

I'm afraid I'm still stuck! I've been trying to figure out a little more but to no avail. I'll outline a little code to hopefully make my issue clearer.

**My models**

student

```
scores:   DS.hasMany('score', {async: true}),  
name:     DS.attr('string')
```

objective

```
name:     DS.attr('string'),
scores:   DS.hasMany('score', {async : true})
```

score

```
scoreResult:  DS.attr('number'),
objective:    DS.belongsTo('objective', {async: true}),
student:      DS.belongsTo('student', {async: true})
```

3. So what I'd really like to do is in the "student" controller set the "score" property to the "scoreResult" integer, filtering by the value of the objective_id in the score model.

So elsewhere, I'll be able choose an objective, gets its objective_id, and then use this to set the student controller's "score" to that for the appropriate objective.

I hope this makes sense. I'm really struggling to find any tutorial/guidance for this, and struggling to figure it out for myself. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: For part 2, you should include code for your models, routes, and controller(s). Also, it's not clear what you mean by 'chosen' objective. How is it chosen? Maybe include the template code as well.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm going to be a little slow replying, I'm going to try and figure out a few other things and then come back to this. Thanks

Comment: I'll take another look at your issue, when I have some time. In the mean time, if you could create a jsbin, it would make it easier to understand what you're trying to do, and find the problem.

Comment: @rjoxford are you trying to get score of student based on objective_id ?

Answer (score 1):

```
return this.get('scores.firstObject');
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working. I've tried just about every syntactic variation. The best I can get is either "undefined",  "<subclassofDS.PromiseArray):ember553>"    or
 <client@model:score::ember362:2>.  Just can't seem to work this out, or find any documentation. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of extra arguments. You can add other arguments by using something like this

```
score : Ember.computed('first','second','third', function(){
      //now use all three properties to do anything here
      // you can use any number of properties
      return this.get('model').filterBy('first',A);
});
```

Another syntax but with same meaning will be

```
score : function(){

}.property('first','second','third')
```

Comment: I understand this as a way of working out computed properties.  I'm trying to set a property to the value of an attribute on a related model. I can set to a attribute on the model itself, it seems to be the one to many relationship that's causing issues.